# Two CheckBoxList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

Model selects from a database list of products to their categories. On the form you want to display CheckBoxList with a list of categories and another with a list of items in this one (or more) category. Immediately after selecting the category list of products to be updated. How can this be implemented?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i done with Kendo UI controls like KendoListView. Is it preferable to you?

Answer (score 0):

I normally use below approach when dealing with checkboxes check whether it helps you.

**Model:**

```
namespace GateApplication.Models
{
    public class Gate
    {
        public string PreprationRequired { get; set; }
        public List<CheckBoxes>  lstPreprationRequired{ get; set; }
        public string[] CategoryIds { get; set; }
    }

    public class CheckBoxes
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

Load CheckBox Value:

```
public ActionResult Create()
   {
      List<CheckBoxes> lstchk = new List<CheckBoxes>()
            {
                new CheckBoxes {Text="coduit", Value="coduit" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="safety", Value="safety" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="power", Value="power" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="access", Value="access" }

            };

          var model = new Gate
            {
               lstPreprationRequired=lstchk
            };

            return View(model);
   }
```

**View:**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.lstPreprationRequired)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Value" name="CategoryIds" value="@item.Text"/>
                  <label for="optionId">@item.Text</label>
       <br />
    }
```

Now your view shold have list of checkboxes. Now saving CheckBox values to the database.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Gate ViewModel,FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {

            Gate gate = new Gate();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                gate.PreprationRequired = Request.Form["CategoryIds"];// here you'll get a string containing a list of checked values of the checkbox list separated by commas

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gate.PreprationRequired))//this is used when no checkbox is checked
                    gate.PreprationRequired = "None,None";

                Save();//Save to database
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Now you have below kind of string in your database

> safety,power,access

Now fetch the selected values and display the view.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
           List<CheckBoxes> lstchk = new List<CheckBoxes>()
            {
                 new CheckBoxes {Text="coduit", Value="coduit" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="safety", Value="safety" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="power", Value="power" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="access", Value="access" }
             };

            var model = new Gate
            {
                lstPreprationRequired =lstchk,
                CategoryIds = "safety,power,access".Split(',')//here get your comma separated list from database and assign it to the CategoryIds string array, i have used sample text for the values


            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

**View:**

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.lstPreprationRequired)
        {
             <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Value" name="CategoryIds" value=@item.Text" 
             @foreach (var c in Model.CategoryIds)
             {
               if(c == item.Value)
               {
                  <text> checked="checked"</text>
               }
             }
             <label for="optionId">@item.Text></label>
        }
```

Let me know if this does not help you.

Comment: I have two CheckBoxList on one form. When you select an item in the first CheckBoxList (category) should change the second CheckBoxList.